# Cursor only moving horizontally on a macbook 6.2 with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse, macbook

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 on a Macbook pro 6.2, the touchpad and external USB mouse worked perfectly. After restarting the system, I can't get either touchpad or external USB mouse to work. Sometimes there is no cursor, but more often I can only move the cursor horizontally **⅚** of the way across the monitor from the top left. I have uninstalled `mouseemu`. `xinpu` list shows the USB mouse. xinput query-state for the USB mouse shows the following:

```
ButtonClass
    button[1]=up
    ...
    button[16]=up
ValuatorClass Mode=Relative Proximity=In
    valuator[0]=480
    valuator[1]=2400
    valuator[2]=0
    valuator[3]=3
```

and re-issuing this command with the pointer at its right hand extreme displays the same except for:

```
    valuator[0]=1679
```

So the `valuator[0]` seems to be the x-coordinate of the cursor and the range of motion 480-1679 is indeed about **⅚** of the display width (1440). But `valuator[1]` is suspiciously large given the display height is 900. Perhaps this is a side-effect of having previously been using a dual monitor although booting with that monitor connected does not help.

There are other entries listed under `xinput` list:

1. Virtual core XTEST pointer which seems stuck at position (840,1050).
2. bcm5974 which seems stuck at position (837,6700).

Removing the `bcm5974` module using `rmmod` disables the touchpad as expected but does not fix the USB mouse problem. After adding the module back, it is stuck at position (840,1050) instead of (837,6700).

`etc/X11/xorg.conf` was generated by `nvidia-settings` and contains:

```
Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
```

Comment: A couple things -- what did you do between reboots after installing? Does it work if you boot from a livecd? It may help to remove your xorg.conf file and try using the nouveau (OSS) drivers for the nvidia card and see if things work under that config. Add things back in from there until you discover the issue.

Comment: @balloons. Good suggestion. I now am in a repeatable state. With no xorg.conf I can boot with no external monitor. Using NVIDIA to detect dual displays and create a xorg.conf works providing I keep the external monitor plugged in. If I reboot without the external monitor, I need to remove xorg.conf first otherwise I'm back to the above symptoms. This at least gives me a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

**Answered in comments by balloons**

As a work around, it may help to remove your xorg.conf file and try using the nouveau (OSS) drivers for the nvidia card and see if things work under that config.

Comment: You may be right, but this system no longer exists.

Comment: Just adding to help other users with a similar problem.